# I forgot my sudo password

Tags: passwords, sudo

I forgot my sudo password. 
I want to install  a package and it needs me my sudo password. Every time I enter the password by chance. I get the error of try again.
Would you please tell me how I can recover it or if I can change it in terminal
Thanks a lot

Comment: It's the same as your login

Comment: Actually, I forgot my root password. I don;t think its the same as my login

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) from our sister site will work.

Answer (score 2):

From the official Ubuntu LostPassword documentation:

```
Reboot your computer.
Hold Shift during boot to start GRUB menu.
Highlight your image and press E to edit.
Find the line starting with "linux" and append rw init=/bin/bash at the end of that line.
Press Ctrl + X to boot.
Type in passwd username.
Set your password.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I have access to terminal only. Would you please tell me how I can do this using only terminal.

Comment: @Farshad This answer is for terminal mode.

Comment: The problem is when I want  to reboot my system, it wants me to insert the root password and I forgot the root password. That means I can not reboot my system using terminal

Comment: @Farshad, just remove the power for a 10 seconds.